# polymer 3 build --> custom element js not available

Tags: polymer-3.x

I have a polymer 3 app created with `polymer init`
There I have some custum elements. In my `my-app.js` I importet the custom element js and used the element there.
Everything works but if I build the app with `polymer build` the custom element js file was not generated in the build/es5-bundled/src folder
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have preset set to `es5-bundled` - a bundled build -> the custom element is generated and written to index.html.
You'll find in `index.html` something like `<script crossorigin="">define(['/src/my-app/my-app.js']);</script>`

Comment: I set minify to false but also there was no custom-element.js file generated

Comment: Still, it is not minified, but is bundled, due to that `my-app.js` is inlined to `index.html`.
If you don't need bundled build, you can try with `"preset":"es5-unbundled"` (`polymer.json`).

(I've rectified the answer too.)

Comment: I have no problem with the my-app.js file. That file was generated. Also the my-view1-3. But I have a custom-element, defined in custom-element.js in the src folder and that custom-element.js file is not in the builded src folder.